# Dropzonejs trigger error and cancel upload

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

i'm using Dropzonejs and what I would like to do is essentially simple. But I can't find any article about it.

So on sending the file we trigger an error on nasty .exe and .php files. The dropzonejs interface show an X and and error message. So that's correct. The problem is that it still gets thrown into the on success event, and gets uploaded.

```
uploader.on("sending", function (file, xhr, data) {

    var aDeny = [ // deny file some extensions by default
        'application/x-msdownload',
        'text/php'
    ];

    if($.inArray(file.type, aDeny) !== -1) {
        this.defaultOptions.error(file, 'File not allowed: ' + file.name);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Evil.exe still appears in this success event and gets uploaded. The response only has a string of the file path and file.status is success.

```
uploader.on('success', function (file, response) {

    getData({'dostuff'});

    return file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-success");
});
```

So in my 'sending' event, how can I prevent the file from appearing in the success event?

UPDATE:

Thanks! This is what I needed in the end:

```
var aDeny = [ // deny file some extensions by default
    'application/x-msdownload',
    'text/php'
];

Dropzone.options.uploadWidget = {
    // more config...
    accept: function (file, done) {
        if ($.inArray(file.type, aDeny) !== -1) {
            done("This file is not accepted!");
        }
        else {
            done();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first of all always check the file type on the **server side** to prevent any problems.

Then to filter file types with **Dropzone** you can use:

- [**acceptedFiles**](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-acceptedFiles) option

> The default implementation of accept checks the file's mime type or
>   extension against this list. This is a comma separated list of mime
>   types or file extensions.
>
> Eg.: image/*,application/pdf,.psd
>
> If the Dropzone is clickable this option will also be used as accept
>   parameter on the hidden file input as well.

**Sample:**

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#myId", { 
    url: "/file/post",
    acceptedFiles: 'application/x-msdownload,text/php'
});
```

- [**accept**](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-accept) function

> A function that gets a file and a done function as parameters.
>
> **If the done function is invoked without arguments, the file is
>   "accepted" and will be processed. If you pass an error message, the
>   file is rejected, and the error message will be displayed.** This
>   function will not be called if the file is too big or doesn't match
>   the mime types.

**Sample:**

```
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
  paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
  maxFilesize: 2, // MB
  accept: function(file, done) {
    if (file.name == "justinbieber.jpg") {
      done("This file is not accepted!");
    }
    else { done(); }
  }
};
```

Comment: I think, justin bieber detection should be more robust :))